# Laravel capture/override fetch/select query events

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.3

So I am working on an app where I need to cache specific `SELECT` queries using any of methods used by laravel such as `find`, `all`, `select`, `get`, etc.

I know there are events to capture for [delete/update/save](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events). Is anything similar there for `SELECT`ish type of queries ? Somewhere I saw one could use `newFromBuilder` method to capture fetch queries:

```
public function newFromBuilder($attributes = array())
{
    $instance = parent::newFromBuilder($attributes);

    $instance->fireModelEvent('loaded', true);

    return $instance;
}
```

But I think above can be used only AFTER query was actually run whereas I want to override any fetch query to add them to cache.

P.S I know I can use `CacheTags` with the help of some Laravel Pcakages out there but problem is that I don't have any driver that supports cache tags.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I *think* I figured it out, we can override `newBaseQueryBuilder`:

```
protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
{
    $conn = $this->getConnection();

    $grammar = $conn->getQueryGrammar();

    $builder = new Builder($conn, $grammar, $conn->getPostProcessor());

    // do our stuff with builder

    return $builder;
}
```

Comment: I just want to know that which `Builder` is using. It's a Database Builder or Query Builder.